# karaf 3.0.1 not starting up

Tags: maven, apache-karaf, karaf

I'm trying to start karaf 3.0.1 in a solaris box (without internet) but getting the following error:

> karaf: Ignoring predefined value for KARAF_HOME
>   Could not resolve mvn:org.eclipse/org.eclipse.osgi/3.8.2.v20130124-134944

and in karaf.log:

> Jun 30, 2014 12:21:09 PM org.apache.karaf.main.Main main
>   SEVERE: Could not launch framework
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve mvn:org.eclipse/org.eclipse.osgi/3.8.2.v20130124-134944
>          at org.apache.karaf.main.util.SimpleMavenResolver.resolve(SimpleMavenResolver.java:59)
>          at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.createClassLoader(Main.java:315)
>          at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.launch(Main.java:234)
>          at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.main(Main.java:171)

the bundles are well in place (system folder) and the org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg file states:

> org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories=\
>      file:${karaf.home}/${karaf.default.repository}@id=system.repository, \
>
> file:${karaf.data}/kar@id=kar.repository@multi\
>
> http://repo1.maven.org/maven2@id=central,\
>
> http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release@id=spring.ebr.release,\
>
> http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external@id=spring.ebr.external

I've tried running the framework using the three methods (server, service, client) but nothing seems to be working.

my environment is:

> KARAF_BASE=/export/home/mehdi/bin/karaf
>
> KARAF_HOME=/export/home/mehdi/bin/karaf
>
> KARAF_ETC=/export/home/mehdi/bin/karaf/etc
>
> KARAF_DATA=/export/home/mehdi/bin/karaf/data
>
> JAVA_HOME=/opt/temp/jre1.7.0_13

I googled a bit and found a workaround which says to add -h 127.0.0.1 to the client script, but still nothing.

Comment: Maybe replace the "\" after "@multi" by a "," and remove the trailing "," after "ebr.external"?

Comment: it was a problem of formatting, I edited the post. I tried removing the last "," and the spaces between "," and "\" but still the same error. isn't there a way to activate DEBUG for the startup process ?

Comment: I still don't see a comma after "@multi", which might be a cause of not finding a JAR in the declared repos.

Comment: I found out what the problem was, there was no settings.xml in the /.m2 folder, I added it, and now the framework is starting, but I'm still not able to get a console, when starting the framework complaints about the following missing dependencies:
Unable to resolve 4.0: missing requirement [4.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.ops4j.util.property)(version>=1.4.0)) 
Unable to resolve 6.0: missing requirement [6.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.ops4j.net)(version>=1.4.0))